# Advice on Laravel access right depending on entity status

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've built a management platform for a small business and actually working on a v2 with Laravel 5.4.

The context is the following:

- Main managed entity is as Mandate.
- It has several items that may be managed(CRUD)
- Users can be invited to this Mandate and have different roles: Responsible, main broker, sub broker.
- Some users with "global" rights may have access to all mandates, like secretary or the ceo.
- And the part tricky part, access rights change depending on the Mandate status.

Regarding the global access rights, I've got it all covered with activity/role based access.

Mandate access rights are stored in a dedicated table storing the following :

```
mandate_status_id
role_identifier
action_identifier
is_authorized
```

The way I'm handling access right on the main entity is bugging me and I would like to refactor it. What's bothering me is that on every access check I have to determine the current user role regarding mandate being "touched". The mandate acces rights table is loaded into a singleton on every request.

I went at first for a caching approach of the rights/role but it showed its limit when rights did not change after mandate status did.

I was thinking something like building the mandate access or a mandate context when instanciating the mandate model. It would prepare the users having access and their rights.

I'm open to suggestion, if you think I'm approaching it the wrong way please do tell

Comment: maybe consider using policies, policies can be added as a middleware so that way you can maybe group routes per role .

Comment: Yep I'm doing that right now, the thing is everytime I do a @can or check authorization, I've got to check check the user against the mandate to get it's role(s) then check if it has access. Middleware could be the place to instanciate that context I was thinking of

Comment: try this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I work with permissions I add this to the boot method in the AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        $gate->before(function ($user, $ability) {
            if (! $user->isActive()) {
                return false;
            }

            if ($user->isAdmin()) {
                return true;
            }

            if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
                return true;
            }

            if (in_array($ability, $user->getAbilities())) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
```

and then in User model I have the getAbilities that takes the permissions from the DB. And that looks like this:

```
public function getAbilities()
{
    return $this->role->permissions->pluck('description')->toArray();
}
```

Now you need to create a permissions model and set the permissions in the dataabse.

Hope it helps

Comment: I could use this kind of approach, will look into it